# iPhone TabBar Controller Usage

Tags: iphone, tabbar

I want make a typical tabbar based application.

And I want to insert login view on startup before main tabbar is shown.

I tried to insert TabbarController in main view, but cannot find appropriate code. All sample code I found is insert TabbarController on startup. (in Delegate file)

My fellow suggest create toolbar on startup but hide it at login view, but I am not sure if this is a general method or not.

In this case, what is a 'recommanded' handling method of TabbarController ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to

1-Add the tab bar to UIWindow in the appDelegate as is suggested by apple.

2-then add a UINavigationController in tabbar using tabbarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObject:yourNavController];

3- Now after alloc init on your login controller write this code before pushing it to the navigation controller of the tabbar
yourLoginController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=true;

4- push yourloginViewController to the navigation controller of the tabbar.

5- After authentication before pushing your MainviewController instance on the navigation set it like this
MainviewController .hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=false;

I hope these five simple steps will do the magic for you cheers :)
Please let me know if it helps you.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The approach I use for login screens which works great is:

- prepare and show the regular main screen (tab bar controller with whatever initial VC you want to use)
- immediately present the login screen modally (without animation) from the tab bar controller (which will obscure the tab bar controller, which is what you want)
- make the login screen the startup image